# A table is made of $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ boxes where we randomly write numbers. Calculate the probability that $\max_1 < \max_2 < ... < \max_n$

Tags: probability

Given a natural number $n \geq 1$, consider a table made up of $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ boxes, arranged in $n$ rows: one box in the first row, two in the second, etc., $n$ boxes in the $n$th row. In the boxes of the table we randomly write numbers from $1$ to $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$. Let $m_k$ be the largest of the numbers in the $k$th row. Calculate the probability that $m_1 < m_2 < ... < m_n$

I think that it can be illustrated with such an array, in the example $n = 6$. That gives us $\frac{6(6 + 1)}{2} = 21$ boxes.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |  |  |  |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |  |  |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |

The max values in the rows are: $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21$.

First I thought that all the arrangements of values in an array that are correct would be those made by permuting numbers in each row. However, that is not that simple since for example we could change places of $2$ and $4$ and that would be correct. However, not all permutations in columns are valid, since interchanging places of $1$ and $4$ would make the arrangement of values incorrect.

Therefore, I can't find any scheme to find all correct arrangements of values in the boxes.

Comment: I believe induction works here. You might be able to see a pattern if you directly compute the probabilities up to $n \le 4$ or $5$.

Comment: Have you solved any small cases or carried out a simulation study?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the probability that $m_1<m_2<\dots<m_n$.

Suppose $n\ge 1$. In order for the event $m_1<m_2<\dots<m_{n}$ to occur, two things must happen.

- First of all, the largest number of the triangle, $n(n+1)/2$, must be placed in the $n^\text{th}$ row. There are $n$ spots in this row, so the probability that this occurs is $n/(n(n+1)/2)=2/(n+1)$.
- Second, we need it to be the case that $m_1<m_2<\dots<m_{n-1}$. The event that this occurs is just a smaller version of the same problem, with only $n-1$ rows. Therefore, the probability of this is $p_{n-1}$.

Note that the events in the two bullet points are independent of each other. This is because the event in the second bullet only depends on the relative orderings of the entries in the first $n-1$ rows, so it does not matter which entries were placed in the $n^\text{th}$ row.

Since these two are independent, we conclude
$$
p_n=\frac2{n+1}\cdot p_{n-1}\qquad (n\ge 2)
$$
This leads to a proof by induction that $p_n=2^{n}/(n+1)!$ for all $n\ge 1$.